# Result of NSPredicate as a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS 'aaa'"];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@"anystringaaaggg"];
```

Result is true. But I need to create an NSString that will contain "aaa". How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to add "aaa" to a existing string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't work that way.

For example, how could you create a string that equals "Steve" OR "Novikoff"? Yet you *can* create a predicate to check for the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

You said result is True for the above code so u need to make NSString object.

```
NSPredicate *predicate;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS 'aaa'"];
//this is for NSString object
NSString *checkMe=@"anystringaaaggg";
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:checkMe];
```

Then we can use this checkMe  as string object and use anywhere u want

OR

```
//other object
id *checkMe=anyObject;
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",checkMe]];
NSString *result=[checkMe stringValue];
```

Then we can use this result  as string object and use anywhere u want